# TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str, I am getting the following error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am getting this error when I fit my model. This is a model to generate captions from images, I don't the error because I am new to keras. the code below with generated error.

```
reduce_lr = keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(
monitor="val_loss", factor=0.2, patience=3
)
# Create an early stopping callback.
early_stop = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
monitor="val_loss", patience=5, restore_best_weights=True
)
history = dual_encoder.fit(
train_dataloader,
epochs=num_epochs,
#validation_data=val_dataloader,
#callbacks=[reduce_lr, early_stop],
)
print("Training completed. Saving vision and text encoders...")
vision_encoder.save("vision_encoder")
text_encoder.save("text_encoder")
print("Models are saved.")

Epoch 1/5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-745dd79762e6> in <module>()
 15 history = dual_encoder.fit(
 16     train_dataloader,
---> 17     epochs=num_epochs,
 18     #validation_data=val_dataloader,
 19     #callbacks=[reduce_lr, early_stopping],

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in 
wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
992           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
993             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 994               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
995             else:
996               raise

TypeError: in user code:


/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:853 train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
<ipython-input-20-9b27a9a3b9e9>:18 call  *
    caption_embeddings = text_encoder(features["caption"], training=training)

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

This is the complete code of my colab coding[PLEASE CLICK ON THIS LINK](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wjmlb2hx-VSMhRTYOQ2jTmBlR1KcuBs8?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is not a Keras problem, the features variable is a tuple, not a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks Sir for your comment, Is it the train and validation dataset format problem that I am passing to dual_encoder.fit or what?

Comment: The error happens in this line: caption_embeddings = text_encoder(features["caption"], training=training) (I am only interpreting the error msg), so you need to find out and trace back what makes the features variable here.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Sir you seem to be very good in Keras. I am using a Keras model [LINK IS HERE](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/nl_image_search/). Here they have used          `text_encoder(features["caption"]` and 
   `vision_encoder(features["image"]` If you check in `class DualEncoder`. I want to these two features location in the given keras code. Once I knew the location and type of these two features then I will make same features in my new dataset to apply this model.